# SSRS with Report Viewer issues not refreshing

Tags: iis, reporting-services, webforms, report, reportviewer

Hi i wonder if anyone can help me, I am absolutely stuck on this one. I will start from the beginning so you understand what I am trying to accomplish.

I have a web page which displays total figures in a grid, below the grid I have a Report Viewer which displays these figures as a line graph via an SSRS report on the server. Recent requirements would like the grid to be filterable, so if they want to see totals for a specific customer or product. While I have this working I would also like the SSRS report within the report viewer to also so the same information.

Now I have this semi working, I have made the necessary changes to the report on the server and this is working correctly, next was to hook that all up with the Report Viewer. I also have this working to a degree. Basically what is happening is if the Async is flase then the report does not refresh even ater telling it to. If I turn Async on it works as expected on my computer with IIS7 however when I upload this to our server with IIS6 after the initial load, when a postback happens or when I try to filter the grid I just get a blank screen. Its like the report is not being displayed.

Any help would be appreciated as I have previously used SSRS with report viewer to get a different report based on option buttons which works, but this does not seem to on the server. Locally it is fine but not where it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out and while it has taken me a while to get the time to post it on here, I thought I should, just in-case someone else comes across this issue. 
So Async ="true" the report is displayed in the report viewer for the first time after any postback occurs I am left with a blank screen. If I turn Async = "false" then I get the report the first time but the report never refreshes. After fiddling for a while it got me thinking if it works the first time then that is all I need and just pass different parameters to the report. So I set Async = "false" and had a look as to how to completely reset the report viewer control. Turns out all I needed was ReportViwerControl.Reset(). This reset the control to its default like almost like we are using it for the first time. Then I apply the report details and parameters and hey presto the report works as expected and the report changes every time a filter is set.

I uploaded this to the server and it is working as expected. Quite why it wouldn't before I am unsure however, i do have to stress that the server is old and has old technology, the reason for IIS6. While our test server and my local copy have the latest technology.

Thank you all very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try . Set enable 32 bit to true

Below is how you do it from IIS7 manager:
    1   Right click on the Application Pool and select “Advanced Settings…” or select the same from the Actions pane after selecting the Application pool.
    2   Change the “Enable 32-bit Applications” to True (if you want the application pool to spawn in a 32-bit mode)
    3   Click OK.

Comment: Hi I just checked my local version of IIS7 and enable32bit is set to false. The issue I am having is on IIS6, if at all this is an IIS issue.